# Updating missing values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, fillna

I have a large dataframe (df) broken down into numerical (num_data) and categorical data (cat_data). As I understand it these are "slices" of the main dataframe.

When I fill the missing values and then reevaluate for missing values I get the same missing values even though I'm not getting any errors when I fill.

This is how I'm slicing up the data.

```
cat_data = df.select_dtypes(include='object')
num_data = df.select_dtypes(exclude='object')
```

This is a sample of the data in question

[image: Here is an image of a sample of the data]

I am using this to evaluate missing values

```
num_data.isna().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

And I am using this to replace those missing values

```
# 3a. Fill missing lot frontage values with mean value
df['LotFrontage']=df['LotFrontage' ].fillna(df['LotFrontage' ].mean() )
# 3a. Fill missing MasVnrArea with 0
df['MasVnrArea']=df['MasVnrArea'].fillna(0)
```

I don't get any errors when I run this.

But when I evaluate for missing variables again after filling these values I get the same number of missing values for these variables. I feel like I'm misunderstanding some part of this process which I suspect has to do with changes to the main df vs. updating the info in num_data.

[image]

EDIT:

After some advice from @AlexandreDaly it seems I had some empty strings and not missing values.

When I look for value counts to establish where my missing strings are coming from I get

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuK6f.png)

Which is strange that this value of 70.049958 occurs 259 times because that is the same number I get when I use

```
num_data.isna().sum().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

So why would this value be registering as NAN? Or is that just coincidence and the real values I'm looking for are elsewhere in the data? Does anyone know how to expand the list to show all 111 unique values? It seems like everything in this column is a value but I cant see all of it yet.

DISCOVERY!
My LotFrontage variable is an Int64 datatype (an integer) and one value that was repeatedly entered (70.04) is a float.

So now my question has become, What is the best way to change the datatype of a specific column in pandas? Or is that even the approach I should be taking?

Thank you in advance kind internet strangers, its my first question on StackOverflow so any constructive advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can you add a mock/small dataframe that reflects your data frame in your question? You're more likely to get a solution this way.

Comment: Clarifying question - are you sure these are NaNs and not empty strings? What do you get if you  run: df['LotFrontage'].isnull().sum() and/or df['MasVnrArea'].isnull().sum()?

Comment: @AlexandreDaly Thank You! I suspected I was missing something like this. When I ran your suggested code for both variables it returned 0. So what are empty strings and how do I find them and get rid of them?

Comment: Got it - sounds like you don't have NaNs then, which is why your fillna() isn't working. What I'd do is: df['LotFrontage'].value_counts() and df['MasVnrArea'].value_counts(). That'll show you what the unwanted values are, then you can just use the same function you had, only now with .replace() rather than .fillna().

Comment: @MarceloPaco Thanks for the tip! I will remember to include a sample of the data in future posts. I edited the post to include an image of a sample of the dataframe but I don't have enough reputation yet to embed images so its just an imgur link.

Comment: @AlexandreDaly Is there an easy way to expand the list of value counts so I can see all of them? I'm working in a Jupyter notebook if that matters but its showing an abbreviated list (which i edited into the question) and everything I see is as value. And strangely the most common value of 70.04(etc.) occurs 259 times which is the same number I'm getting from isna(). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point this is a new question, so I'd recommend you set as "answered" and start a new query.

That said, to set a new column type you could do:

```
df['col_to_ints'] = df['col_to_ints'].astype(int)
```

or:

```
df['col_to_floats'] = df['col_to_floats'].astype(float)
```

depending on what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thank you! I think everyone else just posted comments and since this was my first post I didn't know how to mark them as an answer. Is that possible? I imagine lots of comments actually answer the question someone is asking, whereas sometimes the answer that is accepted isn't answering the intended question. I marked your response as the accepted answer, appreciate your time!